# Which airspace requires what RNP?

Tags: flight-planning, airspace, ifr-navigation, rnp

How do I know which airspace requires what RNP value? More specifically, can I go from NY to London with just BRNAV providing I stay above the NAT HLA?

Comment: Check the local AIP.

Comment: @J.Hougaard - In the NY–London example, last I checked the US AIP deviates from ICAO and does not list RNP values.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, Please refer to the following website:

https://www.uasc.com/docs/default-source/documents/whitepapers/uasc_rnp-rnav_whitepaper.pdf

Here are some extracts that allow to compare US and European requirements:

> **US Airspace Requirements**
>
> The current US RNP requirements are:
>
> - RNP-10 as described in FAA order 8400.12c
> - RNP-4 as described in FAA Order 8400.33
> - RNAV (RNP AR) approach authorization as defined in Advisory Circular (AC) 90-101a
> - Basic RNP capability is achieved through TSO-C146 compliant equipment when installed under AC 20-138().
>
> RNP-10 and RNP-4 procedures are limited primarily to oceanic airspace.
>
> RNAV (RNP AR) procedures are available in the US for domestic
>   operations. These procedures require approval, hence the name:
>   Authorization Required (AR), formally known as Special Aircraft &
>   Aircrew Authorization Requirements (SAAAR) procedures.
>
> **European Airspace Requirements**
>
> There are two existing European RNP requirements:
>
> - Basic-RNAV (B-RNAV), equivalent to RNP-5 (reference FAA AC 90-45A, AC 20-130, AC 20-138, and AC 25-15)
> - Precision-RNAV (P-RNAV), equivalent to RNP-1.
>
> These requirements are defined in European Aviation Safety Agency
>   (EASA) Temporary Guidance Leaflet (TGL)-10, and FAA AC 90-96A. A
>   statement is required in the Aircraft Flight Manual (AFM) or AFM
>   Supplement (AFMS).
>
> For European operations, a Letter of Authorization (LOA) for all RNP
>   operations, is necessary, as the requirements differ from the FAA
>   requirements.